# Executing legacy opengl code in codeblocks

Tags: c, opengl, glut, undefined-reference

I have an old program that uses legacy opengl. I am attempting to run the code, but I have been stumbling into some errors. I installed `freeglut` and attempted to link it and add the includes, and while it seems to execute, I get an error in the process that states:

```
undefined reference to `_imp___glutInitWinExit@12
```

The bit of code in the `freeglut_std.h` header file that is causing the error is located at:

```
static void FGAPIENTRY FGUNUSED glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK(int *argcp, char **argv_ { _glutInitWithExit(argcp, argv, exit); }
```

This is line 637 of the code, so I presume I linked freeglut properly, but for some reason is stopping just short of execution. I am not sure what steps I should take from here, and any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: Build log (a snippet of it) -

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:637: undefined reference to `_imp____glutInitWithExit@12'
obj\Debug\curve.o: In function `glutCreateWindow_ATEXIT_HACK':
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:639: undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateWindowWithExit@8'
obj\Debug\curve.o: In function `glutCreateMenu_ATEXIT_HACK':
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:641: undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateMenuWithExit@8'
obj\Debug\curve.o: In function `curve_buildLine':
```

Comment: Can you add the build log to the question?

Comment: Can you `#define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK` before `#include <gl\glut.h>`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat done, @Wyck there is no `#include <gl\glut.h>` in the `freeglut_std.h` header file.

Comment: Wyck is spot on. #define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK prior to including the glut headers (or freeglut, or any other variation of glut).